# Sqlite inserting doesn't work properly

Tags: java, android, sqlite

First time writing Android app here.

My use case is following: in one activity I have a `TextView` that displays a summary (sum of amounts), and a `Button` with `EditText`. The idea is that pressing the button adds an entry to sqlite database.

The problem is, every time I press the button, it seems that the **previous value from the input** is being added to the database.

1. Input 10 -> press button -> **no reaction**
2. Input 7 -> press button -> **summary changes by 10**
3. Input 3 -> press button -> **summary changes by 7**
   etc.

Here's the method used in the OnClickListener:

```
public static void addExpense(Context ctx, Expense expense) {
        ExpensesDbHelper dbHelper = new ExpensesDbHelper(ctx);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();


        ContentValues values = expense.toContentValues();
        Log.i("Daily-", "addExpense: " + values.toString());

        long newRowId;
        db.beginTransaction();
        try {
            newRowId = db.insert(
                    ExpensesReaderContract.ExpenseEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                    null,
                    values);

            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } finally{
            db.endTransaction();
        }


        Log.i("Daily-", "addExpense: new id " + newRowId);
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) from entry", null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        Log.i("Daily-", "Number of rows: " + c.getInt(0));
        c.close();

        Log.i("Daily-", "addExpense: Existing " + Expense.printable(getExpenses(db)));
    }
```

Here's the log statements from that sequence of inputs:

```
I/Daily-: addExpense: timestamp=2015-11-07 16:44:38 comment=Expense amount=10.0
I/Daily-: addExpense: new id 1
I/Daily-: Number of rows: 1
I/Daily-: addExpense: Existing 
I/Daely-Log: 9
I/Daily-: addExpense: timestamp=2015-11-07 16:44:41 comment=Expense amount=7.0
I/Daily-: addExpense: new id 2
I/Daily-: Number of rows: 2
I/Daily-: addExpense: Existing Expense(10.000000,Expense,2015-11-07T16:44:38.000Z), 
I/Daely-Log: 9
I/Daily-: addExpense: timestamp=2015-11-07 16:44:44 comment=Expense amount=3.0
I/Daily-: addExpense: new id 3
I/Daily-: Number of rows: 3
I/Daily-: addExpense: Existing Expense(7.000000,Expense,2015-11-07T16:44:41.000Z), Expense(10.000000,Expense,2015-11-07T16:44:38.000Z),
```

And here's the code from the activity that handles the flow of events:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_summary);
        showAvailable();

        Button addExpenseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_expense);
        final EditText amountField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amount);

        addExpenseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    float amount = Float.parseFloat(amountField.getText().toString());
                    addExpense(amount, "Expense");

                    showAvailable();
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

                }
            }

        });
    }
```

Now it is clear that after `db.insert` returns, the row is still not where it should be.

How do I guarantee that next call to getExpenses definitely returns the new row?

Appreciate your help.

**Update**: `Expense` is a very simple class:

```
public class Expense {
    public static DateFormat iso8601Format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    private float amount;

    public float getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public String getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public DateTime getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    private String comment;
    private DateTime timestamp;

    public Expense(float amount, String comment, DateTime timestamp) {
        this.amount = amount;
        this.comment = comment;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
    ...
     public ContentValues toContentValues() {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(ExpensesReaderContract.ExpenseEntry.COLUMN_NAME_AMOUNT, getAmount());
        values.put(ExpensesReaderContract.ExpenseEntry.COLUMN_NAME_COMMENT, getComment());
        values.put(ExpensesReaderContract.ExpenseEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TIMESTAMP, iso8601Format.format(getTimestamp().toDate()));
        return values;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you clarify this class Expense, from where you are getting the ContentValues object is populated, as many times this causes the error

Comment: @PankajNimgade added relevant code. As I mentioned, the whole think works but with a weird transactional delay.

Comment: in your code you are not performing any heavy duty task so this should not give you any lag as you are getting in your case. can you try performing this task on a separate thread than the UI. you might want to try AsyncTask,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logs indicate that the insert indeed *does work* -- you're getting the correct `COUNT(*)` out, aren't you? I would be more concerned about problems in `Expense.printable()` and `getExpenses()`, but you appear to have cut out that part of the code when you posted it. Most likely, you're losing a row somewhere around there.

If I were to guess, you're doing something like this in your `getExpenses()` method:

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
        <stuff>
    }
}
```

That would make you miss the first row. If that proves to be your problem, just skip the `moveToFirst()` call, or change the loop to a do-while.

Comment: I knew I was going to be punished for copying code from tutorials.. Thanks, that was the problem.

Comment: That's a good lesson: never copy code without *really* understanding it. It sometimes causes problems, like it did for you this time, but more importantly, it means you're missing out on an opportunity to learn something and become better!

Comment: @SnildDolkow, In complete agreement with you mate.